# Swift syntax: lazy

Tags: swift

Today I saw some code which confused me:

```
lazy var variable ＝ {......}()
```

I hope someone can explain for me the usage of `lazy`.

Comment: Please do not use images for code. Image links can become invalid and then nobody knows what the question is about. Also, we can't copy&paste the code to play around with it. So please **edit your question** and add the code you're talking about.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion,forgiving me for I am a new member in stack overflow,i will be careful to it next time.The code as follow:    lazy var managedObjectModel:NSManagedObjectModel = {
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DailyRecord", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL:modelURL)!
    }()

Comment: No sweat, I gave you these hints *because* you're new :-) You are more likely to receive a good answer if you provide a good question. Next time, please really edit your question (click on the *edit* link below the question) when we ask you to do so: code in comments can't be formatted nicely and people often don't look for additional informations in the comments. It's better for you to have all the relevant information in the question itself. Have fun!

Comment: I think so,but I have to tell you the truth that I try to understand the submitted rules many time,I am poor in English so I can't understand the rule.Ha ha!However,I will try my best to follow the rule step by step,I need some time to adapt to it. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lazy var variable: Class ＝ {
   <initialisation>
   return <resulting object>
}()
```

is equivalent to:

```
var _variable: Class?
var variable: Class {
    get{
        if _variable == nil {
            <initialisation>
            _variable = <resulting object>
        }

        return _variable!
    }
}
```

In short: it initialises the object when it is needed

Comment: hello @simpleBob,now I have another problem make me confused,I can't do anything without solving it,now,I am making a app which use core data,but I meet some problem,please help me.....>.<.....

Comment: but I can't ask next question whiting next day in the satckoverflow  @simpleBob.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy initialization (also sometimes called lazy instantiation, or lazy loading) is a technique for delaying the creation of an object or some other expensive process until it’s **needed**. When programming for iOS, this is helpful to make sure you utilize only the memory you need when you need it.

This technique is so helpful, in fact, that Swift added direct support for it with the lazy attribute.

To understand why this is useful, let's first go over the old way of creating lazy properties.

Have a look at this [link](http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

In the example code posted in your question, the lazy qualifier causes the instance variable to be initialized to the assignment once and only when and if the variable is referenced. In this example, the assignment is actually the result of a closure evaluation which could possibly be expensive. Marking the variable as lazy reduces the overhead when instantiating the object by deferring the evaluation of the closure until the variable is actually used. Furthermore, the assignment may have dependencies that would not be satisfied during the normal phase of initialization of the variable, but would be satisfied during the first access of the variable. Hence, the lazy initialization may allow for the variable to be initialized at a more appropriate time.